# .net core file transfer to network location

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have code to transfer files from one location to a network drive. The source location may be my pc or another network drive. I am using .NET Core 2.1 and C#.  I have code similar to what I have below from MSDN examples.

The problem is that this works fine when the target is a folder on my PC, but when it is a network location like below, the file is not moved to the specified location. The file in the source does get removed though and there are no errors whatsoever.

I have ensured that the windows account I'm logged in with has explicit permissions to the network location. I'm assuming that is the context my application is running under. I have also looked around and tried to do impersonation to explicitly use an account with permissions and found some code to do it, but it seems as though that does not work in .net core.

What am I missing? How can I get this to work?

```
string fileName = @"TestFile.txt";
string sourcePath = @"C:\users\myuser\docs";
string targetPath =  @"\\10.10.10.148\docs";

// Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

// To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
// Create a new target folder, if necessary.
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
}

// To copy a file to another location and 
// overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

Comment: I think the account used is the account configured for the application pool for the web site in your IIS.

Comment: @DmitryPavlov I am using windows authentication.  I've already ensured that my user/network account has permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Put your move command inside a try catch block to see the actual error returned (if any).

```
try
{
    // To copy a file to another location and 
    // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
    System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destFile, true);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //show error message using appropriate method for 
    //Console Application
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    //OR Web Application //
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
    //OR WinForms Application
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Then you will have some more information to help troubleshoot.

Comment: It was already in a try catch block.  That did not return anything.

Comment: Apologies. I did not see that in your code. Have you tried running step-by-step in debug? Are you running this within VS or did you compile and then run the executable outside VS? If you are running in VS, then Pavlov's comment above is correct. VS does not necessarily run with your permissions.

Comment: So it turns out that my code was working fine. The issue was with the directory I was writing to. For whatever reason files that were being added were all showing the same date and timestamp. Therefore, I wasn't seeing the files my application was moving or copying. That's a different issue though.